# How Can I change the color of all items Polygon from GoogleMap Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

If I have five items created in my map, How Can I change the color of all items. If I use the click event onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) I can have access to the element selected, but not the others.

```
        map.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {

            // Flip the r, g and b components of the polygon's stroke color.
            int strokeColor = polygon.getStrokeColor() ^ 0x00ffffff;
            polygon.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);

        }
    });
```

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List` or other structure to store your `Polygon`s, and then iterate over it to change the color of the elements:

```
private List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

// Create your polygons and add them to the List
Polygon polygon1 = mMap.addPolygon(yourPolygonOptions1);
polygons.add(polygon1);
Polygon polygon2 = mMap.addPolygon(yourPolygonOptions2);
polygons.add(polygon2);

// ...

// Iterate over the List to change the color
for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
    int strokeColor = polygon.getStrokeColor() ^ 0x00ffffff;
    polygon.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the polygon itself, you can customise it before adding it to the map as shown below:

```
Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
polygon.setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon#setFillColor(int)